# Adding res folder into an Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-resources

Please, I have a project whose res folder content i'll like to import into another android studio project. How do I do this is. What I tried was good old copy and paste but I'm getting this error when I try to build.
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
I think it is because of the way I added the files into the project. Please what is the recommended way to do this?

Edits
@Egor
Changing the name only creates more errors for me. I get this from my gradle log

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name 
(at \u0027label\u0027 with value \u0027@string/app_name\u0027).",
"sources":[{"file":"\\\\?\\C:\\WorkSpace\\RC\\Ovpn\\vpnlib\\build\\intermediates\\manifests\\aapt\\debug\\AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":12,"startColumn":23,"startOffset":379,"endColumn":39,"endOffset":395}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
warning: string 'alwaysonvpn' has no default translation.
\\?\C:\WorkSpace\RC\Ovpn\vpnlib\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error:
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
```

Editing the file gradle is referring to does nothing because it will be overwritten once I build the project again.
So, I thought maybe the error is coming from the AndoridManifest file in the /src/main directory.
The Manifest there has this as content

```
package="com.example.vpnlib">

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

</application>
```

and my /src/main/res/values/strings.xml contains the following

```
<resources>
    <string name="app">OpenVPN for Android</string>
    ....
</resources>
```

Comment: Do your strings.xml file contain string with name app_name?

Comment: You need to merge strings.xml from the new app with the old.

Comment: You need a string with name app_name in your string file. Currently you don't have it. the one which you have start with only app !!

Answer (score 3):

Go to

> res/values/strings.xml

and Add this

`<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>`

Answer (score 1):

You should either add the missing string to your resources, or remove usages of that non-existent string. There's no "recommended way" to move resources, moving files should do the job.

Comment: The easiest solution I see is renaming the "app" string into "app_name", that should build fine.

Comment: I've done this, I get 101 errors saying this: Package R does not exist

Comment: Means you've got more errors in XML files, carefully go through the error messages and figure out what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

it simply means you are referencing a string that doesn't not exist in your string.xml file (under values folder in your res folder).
To fix the issue just create the string app_name in your string.xml.

Answer (score 1):

> copy res folder from old one to new project and check your
>   `AndroidManifest.xml` file under application tag  view  the value of
>   lable
>
> ```
> android:label="@string/app_name"
> ```
>
> simple replace this value with other string or just create `app_name`
>   string under `strings.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

Just copy paste the res folder in new project in android studio, rebuild the project, if such error occurs then manually add the string in your string file.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a valid import to the R files
this is what worked for me

```
import com.examaple."projectname".R
```